# Custom ANTLR grammar not working for every input

Tags: parsing, antlr, business-rules

I am trying to write a grammar for our custom rule engine which uses ANTLR (for parsing) and Pentaho Kettle (for executing the rules)

Valid inputs for the parser would be of the type:
`(<Attribute_name> <Relational_Operator> <Value>) AND/OR (<Attribute_name> <Relational_Operator> <Value>)`
i.e. PERSON_PHONE = 123456789

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar RuleGrammar;
options{
language=Java;
}

prog                : condition;

condition
                                :  LHSOPERAND RELATIONOPERATOR RHSOPERAND
                                ;

LHSOPERAND
                                :  STRINGVALUE
                                ;

RHSOPERAND
                                :  NUMBERVALUE    |
                                   STRINGVALUE
                                ;


RELATIONOPERATOR
                                :   '>'    |
                                     '=>'  |
                                     '<'   |
                                     '<='  |
                                     '='   |
                                     '<>'
                                ;

fragment NUMBERVALUE
                              : '0'..'9'+
                              ;

fragment STRINGVALUE
                              :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')*
                              ;


fragment LOGICALOPERATOR
                              :  'AND' |
                                 'OR'  |
                                 'NOT'
                              ;
```

The issue I am facing is comparing against string value i.e. PERSON_NAME=1 would pass the grammar, but the value `PERSON_NAME=BATMAN` does not work. I am using ANTLRWorks and on debugging for `PERSON_NAME=BATMAN`, I get a `MismatchTokenException` for the RHS value.

Can anyone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the version you're executing? I'm not an ANTLR user, but I find it hard to see how this grammar could fail for that input.

Comment: Does it work if you take out NUMBERVALUE | from RHSOPERAND?

Comment: @Internal Server Error: If I remove `NUMBERVALUE |` and only keep `StringValue`, then ANTLRWorks throws an error `The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RHSOPERAND`. The strange part is if I replace `LHSOPERAND RELATIONOPERATOR RHSOPERAND` with `LHSOPERAND RELATIONOPERATOR LHSOPERAND`, it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BATMAN` is being tokenized as a `LHSOPERAND` token. You must realize that the lexer does not take into account what the parser "needs" at a particular time. The lexer simply tries to match as much as possible, and in case 2 (or more) rules match the same amount of characters (`LHSOPERAND` and `RHSOPERAND` in your case), the rule defined first will "win", which is the `LHSOPERAND` rule.

> #### EDIT
>
> Look at it like this: first the lexer receives the character stream which it converts in a stream of tokens. After all tokens have been created, the parser receives these tokens which it then tries to make sense of. Tokens are *not* created during parsing (in parser rules), but before it.

A quick demo of how you *could* do it:

```
grammar RuleGrammar;

prog
 : condition EOF
 ;

condition
 : logical
 ;

logical
 : relational ((AND | OR) relational)*
 ;

relational
 : STRINGVALUE ((GT | GTEQ | LT | LTEQ | EQ | NEQ) term)?
 ;

term
 : STRINGVALUE
 | NUMBERVALUE
 | '(' condition ')'
 ;

GT          : '>';
GTEQ        : '>=';
LT          : '<';
LTEQ        : '<=';
EQ          : '=';
NEQ         : '<>';
NUMBERVALUE : '0'..'9'+;
AND         : 'AND';
OR          : 'OR';
STRINGVALUE : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')+;
SPACE       : ' ' {skip();};
```

*(note that `EQ` and `NEQ` aren't really relational operators...)*

Parsing input like:

```
PERSON_NAME = BATMAN OR age <> 42
```

would now result in the following parse:

[image]

Comment: Again, thank you very much. I am trying to understand what you have mentioned above. So, when you say "You must realize that the lexer does not take into account what the parser "needs" at a particular time", do you mean that even though I have mentioned `RHSOPERAND`, for the input `PERSON_NAME = BATMAN`, the FIRST closest token match is actually `LHSOPERAND` and that is the reason it assumes the lexer rule as `LHSOPERAND RELATIONOPERATOR LHSOPERAND`

Comment: @darkie15, also see the **EDIT** in my answer.