# Generating AST from ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

For the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382614/custom-antlr-grammar-not-working-for-every-input) and the grammar suggested by @BartKiers (Thank you!), I added the `options` block to specify the output to be

```
options{
language=Java;
output=AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}
```

However, I am not able to figure out how to access the output i.e. `AST`. I need to traverse through the tree and process each operation that was specified in the input.

---

Using your example [here](http://bkiers.blogspot.com/search?updated-min=2011-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&updated-max=2012-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&max-results=11), I am trying to implement rules returning values. However, I am running into following errors:

```
relational    returns [String val]                   
        :  STRINGVALUE ((operator)^ term)?
            {val = $STRINGVALUE.text + $operator.text + $term.text; }
                                    ;

term returns [String rhsOperand]                    
        :  QUOTEDSTRINGVALUE  {rhsOperand = $QUOTEDSTRINGVALUE.text;}
                                    |  NUMBERVALUE               {rhsOperand = $NUMBERVALUE.text; }
                                    | '(' condition ')'
                                     ;
```

Compilation Error:

```
Checking Grammar RuleGrammarParser.g...
\output\RuleGrammarParser.java:495: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable val
location: class RuleGrammarParser
            val = (STRINGVALUE7!=null?STRINGVALUE7.getText():null) + (operator8!=null?input.toString(operator8.start,operator8.stop):null) + (term9!=null?input.toString(term9.start,term9.stop):null); 
            ^
\output\RuleGrammarParser.java:612: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable rhsOperand
location: class RuleGrammarParser
                    rhsOperand = (QUOTEDSTRINGVALUE10!=null?QUOTEDSTRINGVALUE10.getText():null);
                    ^
\output\RuleGrammarParser.java:632: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable rhsOperand
location: class RuleGrammarParser
                    rhsOperand = (NUMBERVALUE11!=null?NUMBERVALUE11.getText():null); 
                    ^
3 errors
```

Can you please help me understand why this fails to compiler?

---

Added the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u1Bv3L0A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By simply adding `output=AST` to the `options` section you don't create a AST, but a flat, 1 dimensional list of tokens. To mark certain tokens as root (or children), you need to do a bit of work.

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr/4933963#4933963) which explains how to create a proper AST *and* get access to the tree the parser then produces (the `CommonTree tree` in the `main` method of the answer I mentioned).

Note that you can safely remove `language=Java;`: by default the target language is Java (no harm in leaving it there though).

Comment: That is awesome! three cheers for @BartKiers !! (& that rhymed :) )

Comment: Can you please help me out with my query above? I have updated the question.

Comment: Bart, found the fix. Maybe you have to update your example to include `$` for all variables defined in the rule.

Comment: @darkie15, yeah, in early version of ANTLR 3, you could safely omit the `$`, which is now mandatory in ANTLR 3.4 (and perhaps 3.3 as well). Note that in the tutorial I provide ANTLR 3.2, which works with all code posted in the tutorial, so I don't think I'll be changing much: I might break something accidentally. Glad to hear you solved your problem, of course.

Comment: I am stuck again :(. I have attached the pastebin link in my post. Basically, I am trying to get the condition as a return value once the parser has validated the input. So for an input like `condition1` where `condition1` might be `NAME = "BATMAN"`, I would get the return value, but for multiple conditions like `NAME = "BATMAN" AND SSN = 0000`, the return value is only the 1st condition and not the second one. Can you please help me out

Comment: @darkie15, not quite sure what you're asking. Better you create a new question and post the code and a decent explanation there, no external links (pastebin) please.